Install Ubuntu 22.04LTS on an old 64 bits desktop that formerly had Win XP
After seemingly finished installation from USB stick I am being told to remove installation medium and then press enter. Having done that I get this message:
( 0.130957) x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS.

Next screen:
CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 19 D1 DF 1D 2D GUID:490D6972 04D2 11DC A650 00E018BFD7CB
PXE-E53: No boot filename receive-d
PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
No bootable device--insert boot disk and press any key.

Another screen shows up sometimes:
Intel Boot Agent PXE Base Code (PXE-2.1 build 086)
Copyright (c) 1997-2007, Intel corporation
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F : Exiting Intel Boot Agent

I have installed and reinstalled close to 10 times now...
And checked all cables..
With the same result.
What is wrong, someone told me that my computer no is compatible with this version of Linux.
Is it better with another older and more light version?

Does this answer your question? Will my device work with Ubuntu?

Check your boot Order in BIOS/uefi your Computer tries to boot over Network.

Can you take a picture of the BIOS screen showing the boot order and add it to your question above?

It's helpful if you're specific with details; you do mention the release (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) but not which product (Server using the subiquity installer, or Desktop using ubiquity  etc).  Your description fits (as I understand it) the bootloader being written to the incorrect device; where writing the ISO (esp. if reformatted) can cause this, but you didn't specify how you wrote ISO & software used, or if you read the summary detail pre-install starting & it looked correct.
